# python3 No Module Named pyaudio

Tags: python, cmd, módulo-python

Sou iniciante em progamação python, por isso estou recebendo o erro/aviso do meu
cmd

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\camar\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 108, in get_pyaudio
    import pyaudio
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyaudio'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\camar\Documents\omega\main.py", line 5, in <module>
    with sr.Microphone() as s:
  File "C:\Users\camar\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 79, in __init__
    self.pyaudio_module = self.get_pyaudio()
  File "C:\Users\camar\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 110, in get_pyaudio
    raise AttributeError("Could not find PyAudio; check installation")
AttributeError: Could not find PyAudio; check installation
```

alguém sabe o que pode ser?

Comment: Que versão do python você usa? Algumas bibliotecas não funcionam nas versões mais recentes. Tente executar seu projeto com o python 3.6 ou 3.5

Answer (score 1):

Você chegou a instalar o `pyaudio`?

Esse `pyaudio` é um módulo, ou seja, um código feito por outra(s) pessoa(s) que você pode incluir no seu projeto. Ele não vem por padrão no Python, então você tem que instalar.

Felizmente, o Python tem uma ferramenta chamada `pip` que cuida da instalação e atualização desses módulos de terceiros.

Experimenta ir no cmd e rodar o comando:

```
python -m pip install pyaudio
```

Isso deve instalar o `pyaudio`, e depois você deve conseguir rodar.